# filter array of objects, where fields are not complete

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have the following array

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Ruan Duarte",
    "idade": 11,
    "work": {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "React"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Raul Dias",
    "idade": 13
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "name": "Caio Ribeiro",
    "idade": 60,
    "work": {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "Rails"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Felipe Lima",
    "idade": 55
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Camila",
    "idade": 25,
    "work": {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Phyton"
    }
  }
]
```

I have an array in this format, where the work.name field in some corners is null. I try to do the filtering as follows ...

```
array.filter((i) => {
  return (
    i.work.name.toLowerCase().normalize("NFD").replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "")
      .includes(search.toLowerCase().normalize("NFD").replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, ""))
  )
})
```

Remembering that I have an input to search and in the state its value is set with search;

However I get an error, because the field is not filled

Comment: do you want the items without or vice versa?

Comment: Try using [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add validation for the object values on `filter` callback.

Here, `i?.work = i ? i.work : undefined`

```js
const array = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Ruan Duarte",
    "idade": 11,
    "work": {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "React"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Raul Dias",
    "idade": 13
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "name": "Caio Ribeiro",
    "idade": 60,
    "work": {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "Rails"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Felipe Lima",
    "idade": 55
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Camila",
    "idade": 25,
    "work": {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Phyton"
    }
  }
]

const search = 'Phy';
console.log(array.filter((i) => {
  return (
    i?.work?.name?.toLowerCase().normalize("NFD").replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "")
      .includes(search.toLowerCase().normalize("NFD").replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, ""))
  )
}));
```

Comment: I'd like to leave my [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-search-box-example-o5gbh) to have a complete React example. Derek was faster with the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution.

```
array.filter((i) => {
  return (
    i.work && i.work.name && i.work.name.toLowerCase().normalize("NFD").replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "")
      .includes(search.toLowerCase().normalize("NFD").replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, ""))
  )
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array.filter(i =>
    i?.work?.name?.toLowerCase().normalize("NFD").replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "")
      .includes(search.toLowerCase().normalize("NFD").replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, ""))
);
```

Optional chaining - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining